# Making certain words in the text clickable in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to application development. I want to make the text coming from the database as below, as in the photo. So I want certain words to be red and clickable. The important detail in this case is that the word should only be like that the first time. In other words, even if there are more than 1 word "dummy" in the text, only the first "dummy" word should be clickable. I tried very hard to do this, but I completely screwed up. I can share my codes if you want. Can anybody help me with this?

```js
const data = {
    text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, dummy when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    highlight: ["dummy", "standard", "since"]
}
```

[image]

Comment: you may read this documentation first https://reactnative.dev/docs/text

Comment: Hi! I read. I know how to make the text red and clickable, but I can't make it the way I described above. Which part of the document solves this problem?

Comment: @SocialNetwork  are you looking for someone to write your code for you

Comment: Noo I said I was just looking at the document but didn't understand which one would solve my problem 

Comment: then i Have another solution for making string clickable , split string into array match your words and wrap them inside anchor or clickable tag. this is vanilajs solution applicable for reactjs, react native or angular